# SQL Server stops responding and server freezes

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, nhibernate

we have a 2008 SQL Server machine, for some reason which we still havent figured out, every two weeks this server stops responding around the same time and around the same day, it's either sunday or saturday, we have checked the logs and the only message we have found is this

> A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out.

On the operating system log we algo found a message

> Application popup: Windows - Virtual Memory Minimum Too Low : Your system is low on virtual memory. Windows is increasing the size of your virtual memory paging file. During this process, memory requests for some applications may be denied. For more information, see Help.

so it looks like the operating system is out of physical memory, we do not undestand why this happens every two weeks, it seems as if memory never gets freed and two weeks is the period it takes to get full. Is there a way we could better diagnose this? we are also wondering if it is related to how we are using NHibernate? or is there any other cause?

Comment: Check your `log file` size. Definitely it is in `GB` :). If so you use below syntax to `shrink` it on regular basis `USE DatabaseName
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE(<TransactionLogName>, 1)
BACKUP LOG <DatabaseName> WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
DBCC SHRINKFILE(<TransactionLogName>, 1)
GO`  Click here to see for **[Reference](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/12/30/sql-server-shrinking-truncate-log-file-log-full/)**

Comment: @ryudice - It is not necessarely SQL Server that's consuming all memory. As a quick check, I would open taskmanager and sort on memory used values. If it really is SQL Server, you can start drilling down.

Comment: @RGI you can't do this anymore, starting with SQL Server 2008. `Msg 155, Level 15, State 1 - 
'TRUNCATE_ONLY' is not a recognized BACKUP option.`

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Sir, please check my reference article mentioned. It clearly states that it is valid for `Sql Server 2008`

Comment: @RGI no, it doesn't. You need to read the link closer, and follow the link that actually talks about SQL Server 2008, and how this is no longer an option.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - sir, can you please share the line number ?

Comment: @RGI line number, what are you talking about? Go back and look closely at [this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/12/30/sql-server-shrinking-truncate-log-file-log-full/). Follow the link in the update at the very first line of the post - it goes to [a new page which shows code that works on SQL Server 2008](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/03/sql-server-shrinkfile-and-truncate-log-file-in-sql-server-2008/), since the code on that page ***DOES NOT***. Or, instead of refusing to believe me, why don't you ***TRY*** the code you posted on SQL Server 2008+ and tell us how well it works?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Sir, you are right. Actually below code should be used to keep the size light weight `ALTER DATABASE DBName SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
DBCC SHRINKFILE(LogFileName, 1)
ALTER DATABASE DBName SET RECOVERY FULL WITH NO_WAIT`

Comment: @RGI perhaps, but I'm not sure how shrinking the log file is going to solve the OP's problem anyway. This seems like cleaning the steering wheel in an effort to get better gas mileage. Except there are potentially negative consequences to shrinking a log file, especially when it is not necessary.

Comment: @AaronBertrand , Sir, The first query that I suggested, I used it few months back. My DB was occupying 55GB space. After shrinking, it was limited to 2.5GB

Comment: @RGI that is disk space. How is it relevant to SQL Server paging out?

Comment: As a suggestion, if you can keep your production SQL server dedicated to just SQL, it should make life much easier. This way SQL can grab just about all of the resources available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) identify the process that consumes the memory. Use the [Process object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804621.aspx) and identify the process that consumes memory (large `Private Bytes` and `Virtual Bytes`)

2) **If** the process turns out to be SQL Server, follow SQL Server memory diagnostics steps. See [Monitoring Memory Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176018%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Using DBCC MEMORYSTATUS to Monitor SQL Server Memory Usage](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271624)

Depending on the identified memory consumer process and posibly on the identified SQL Server memory clerk, appropiate actions and remedies can be recommended, but untill you do the due diligence and find the cause no advice can possibly be given.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server consumes more and more memory over time, this is normal. We faced this issue after the server has been up for a couple of MONTHS. SQL's memory consumption went up to several GB and Windows has eventually cut it down...

**Setting up a "max server memory" for your SQL Server should help.** On our 8 GB server we've set it to 5.5 GB.

PS. Setting up a "low memory" email alert is a good practice. It will let know just **before** the things are about to mess up. This blog [post](http://www.jitbit.com/news/194-setting-up-a-lowmemory-email-alert-on-a-windows-server/) explains how you do this.